# How to add relationships in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried following the documentation found at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/build-web-apps-from-scratch-with-laravel-the-eloquent-orm/ and http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent but it doesnt seem to work.

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public function role()
    {
         return $this->has_one('Role', 'role_code');
    }
}

class Role extends Eloquent 
{
    public function user()
    {
          return $this->belongs_to('User', 'role_code');
    }
}
```

In my database, I have both role_code column in users and roles table.
I used this command in my controller `$test = User::find(1)->role()->get();` But it only displays a blank array. I'm sure there is an entry both in my users and roles tables.

What am I missing? Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Try to turn on the profiler in config/application and see what queries that line generates. The provided code looks fine.

Comment: I agree with TLGreg. Nonetheless, perhaps try using `->first();` instead of `->get();`.

Comment: maybe use lowercase table names (just good practice), aside from that, the snippet looks fine to me.

Comment: @user9507 - please accept some previous answers to some of the questions you have asked. People took the time to help you, so you should take some time to help them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the key field for your role table?  What you've shown us should work *if* the key of the role table is $id.  If not, you'll need to add something like the following to the Role class:

```
public static $key = 'role_code';
```

(I assume that if you're using non-conventional foreign-key definitions, you may have non-conventional primary-key definitions as well.)